# camera Kit get image from frame, Kotlin, Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, camera

I am using camera kit as a preview layer, I am new to kotlin and have flllowed the instruction but i dont seem to be able to get an image from the preview to an imageview when I trigger a button. It gets to the function but the imageview that has a temp image in just disapears..

Below is my code. and below that is the print in the logcat to show the printed lines I set.

```
 cameraBtn.setOnClickListener {
        println("Tony Took image 1")
            cameraKitView.captureImage(CameraKitView.ImageCallback { cameraKitView, capturedImage ->
                val savedPhoto = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo.jpg")
                try {
                    println("Tony got to image 2")
                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(savedPhoto.getPath())
                    var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(savedPhoto.absolutePath)
                    println("Tony got to image 3 in try block")
                    imageTook.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                    outputStream.write(capturedImage)
                    outputStream.close()
                } catch (e: java.io.IOException) {
                    println("Tony got to image 4 in catch block")
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            })
    }
```

> 2019-01-27 21:11:18.701 8191-8191/uk.tonymerritt.appchecker I/System.out: Tony Took image 1
>   2019-01-27 21:11:20.119 8191-8191/uk.tonymerritt.appchecker I/System.out: Tony got to image 2
>   2019-01-27 21:11:20.128 8191-8191/uk.tonymerritt.appchecker I/System.out: Tony got to image 3 in try block

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort this instaed of trying to get the file path and converting that into a bitmap, i was able to take the capturedImage, which is a ByteArray and convert that into a bitmap instead.

```
cameraBtn.setOnClickListener {
        println("Tony Took image 1")

        cameraKitView.captureImage { _, capturedImage ->
            //                    val savedPhoto = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo.jpg")
            try {
                println("Tony got to image 2")
                var bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(capturedImage, 0, capturedImage.size)

                imageTook.setImageBitmap(
                    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                        bmp,
                        imageTook.width,
                        imageTook.height,
                        false
                    )
                )
                println("Tony got to image 3 in try block")
            } catch (e: java.io.IOException) {
                println("Tony got to image 4 in catch block")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```